# Why can't I get data from FindControl?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterSkillUser" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div>
                                        <label ID="id_skill_user" style="display: none;"><%# Eval("id_skill_user") %></label>
                                        <label id="frameworkName"><%# Eval("frameworkName") %></label>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ListLevel" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:DropDownList>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="InputValue" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>




protected async void ButtonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        string id = Request.QueryString["id"];

        foreach (RepeaterItem item in repeaterSkillUser.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                Label idLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("id_skill_user") as Label;
                Label frameworkNameLabel = (Label)(item.FindControl("frameworkName"));
                DropDownList dropdown = (DropDownList)item.FindControl("ListLevel");
                TextBox textbox = (TextBox)item.FindControl("InputValue");

                SkillUserModel data = new SkillUserModel
                    {
                        level = "Random",
                        /* value = dropdown.SelectedValue,*/
                        value = textbox.ToInt()
                    };

                // Add the data to the database
                var response = await skillUserController.Update(idLabel.ToString(), data);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Data sent successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have this aspx and c# code like in above, I want get data like on `FindControl("id_skill_user")`, `FindControl("frameworkName")`, `FindControl("ListLevel")` and `FindControl("InputValue")` to put on Web API, but I get null, how to get data on FindControl like id_skill_user? the data was showing up on frontend but i still get the data null, how to fix this problem? I got no clue.

Comment: Better attach the aspx code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.